# Accepting application/gzip file in POST body

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

All,

I have a instance where I need to accept a gzip file from an HTTP POST in an aspnet core webapi.  I have tried getting it from HTTPContext.Form.Files which obviously didn't work since it is content-type application/gzip.  I have also tried:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
await Decompress(stream, filename);

private async Task Decompress(MemoryStream compressedFileStream, string filename)                            
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        await decompressor.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
            
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
    {
        var content = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(content);
    }
}
```

content is "" so it's not getting the content of what is in the gzip file.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);

await using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
    await decompressor.CopyToAsync(stream1);
                
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream1)) 
    {
        var content = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(content);
    }
}
```

I think the issue is I am not getting the request body correctly.  Any thoughts on that?

Thank you!

Comment: @Jazb the issue is content is "" so it's not reading the stream

Comment: can u try placing the 2nd using block inside the 1st and see if that works? things might be getting disposed of too early...worth a try

Comment: I don't understand why you copy the request stream to a `MemoryStream`, and then copy the uncompressed data to a new `MemoryStream`. Why not just wrap the request body stream in a `GZipStream` and wrap that with a `StreamReader`?

Comment: @Llama I updated my example.  I think the real issue is with how I am getting the request body.    The headers on the POST are: Content-Type - application/gzip
Content-Length - 25038
Filename - test.gz